# AngularJS ng-repeat and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `scope.$first` and `scope.$index` to apply accordion to my content when `ng-repeat` finishes populating it. At first I was using just `scope.$last` but faced this problem - when try to search for some info (using filter) and then turn back to the whole list, accordion doesn't apply.

How to apply accordion when `ng-repeat` finishes and save it further while filtering?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you could provide some code or even better, a working example using jsfiddle (or similar service).

Comment: I will post jsfiddle a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest wrapping the "apply accordion" functionality into a directive.  Define a template for the ng-repeat stuff, then $watch() the model data for changes.  When the $watch triggers, apply the accordion stuff.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/lACrEA-TIto/discussion 
and
http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/